# How to jump to other UINavigationController under another UITab in iOS dev?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have three tabs, namely, `Message`, `Contact`, and `More`. Each tab is a UINavigationController. In the `Contact` tab, we can create a group chat by adding some friends. After click the `Create` button, the view will be navigated to a new view controller in the `Message` tab. However, the navigation controllers in `Message` and `Contact` tab are different; since they are parallel. So I need your help and show me how to realize such functionality.

Here is my code fragment, but it does not work and only return to the root view of `Message`, not the `testvc` view controller.

```
- (IBAction)createGroupButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard];
   UIViewController *testvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testvc"];
   UIViewController *messageTab = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"messageTab"];

   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

   [messageTab.navigationController pushViewController:testvc animated:YES];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: When you switch the tab to "message tab", then delay 1 second to push the "testvc" viewcontroller. I don't know if it works , but try first.

Comment: @liaogang How to delay 1 second? Do you mean sleep the thread for a second? Will it block the app? Thank you.

Comment: @liaogang I tried to delay the `[messageTab.navigationController pushViewController:testvc animated:YES];` for 1 second by using `dispatch_after`, but it does not work.

Comment: You say each tab is a UINavigationController. Then the `UIViewController * messageTab` should be `UINavigationController *messageTab`?

Comment: @liaogang Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is flawed because you are creating a new instance of the `messageTab` view controller - you need to reference the existing instance, which is available from the `viewControllers` property of your tab bar controller -

```
- (IBAction)createGroupButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard];
   UIViewController *testvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testvc"];
   UINavigationController *messageTab = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
   [messageTab pushViewController:testvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work. It only jumps to the first tab's root view controller but with the tab bar in bottom disappeared.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in this method what is `messageTab`? - Enter "po messageTab" in the debugger after stepping over the line that assigns it.

Comment: It prints `<UINavigationController: 0x786326c0>`. @Paulw11

Comment: So, that means that `messageTab` is your navigation controller - try the code in my updated question.

Comment: And one more thing - I presume that testVC *isn't* a UINavigationController, it is just a regular `UIViewController` subclass?

Comment: Yes, `testvc` is a regular `UIViewController` subclass. @Paulw11